# HTML - Textbox And DIV

Tags: html, css

I am creating a social networking site like facebook. So i got a textbox and a right column. The problem is when i resize the textbox the right column goes down with the resized textbox. How could i make the right cloumn div stay?

Here's the code [Click Me To View Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/m5d3B/)

Comment: .rightArea
{
float:right;
padding-right:0pt;
padding-top:40px;
width:244px;
word-wrap:break-word;
margin-top:-1900px;
margin-left:737px;
}

Comment: textarea
{
border:0px none;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
overflow:hidden;
height:30px;
width:450px;
padding:4px;
}

Comment: You should edit your question with the code, not post it as comments. Where is your HTML code?

Comment: actually i could not use the code tag because it gives me error.The error was i must indent it.

Comment: Create a jsfiddle.net with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Change this code in your file after that when you resize your textarea, button will go   next to textarea.
 In Html file:

//<div class="contentText">
   <input type="submit"  class="contentText" value="Post "  id="update_button"  class="update_button"/>
 //</div>

 And 
 In css file:

 textarea { border:0px none; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; overflow:hidden; height:30px; width:450px; padding:4px; float:left;}
```